# How to delete first columns of all dataframes in the global environment?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, lapply

I have a series of dataframes (`df1`, `df2`, `df3`, ..., `dfn`)

They all have two columns and I would like to create a loop or write a function to delete the first column of all my dataframes without changing the original name.

I managed to create a list with all dataframes names with:

```
list_of_dfs = ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) class(get(x))) == 'data.frame']
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 3):

You likely want a combination of `mget` and `lapply`.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3, d=1:3, e=1:3)
df2 <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3, d=1:3, e=1:3)
df3 <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3, d=1:3, e=1:3)
ls(pattern = "^df")
# [1] "df1" "df2" "df3"
dfs <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^df")), function(z) z[,-(1:2)])
dfs
# $df1
#   d e
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
# $df2
#   d e
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
# $df3
#   d e
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution that gets all the dataframes in the environment, removes the first column, and writes the subset back to `.GlobalEnv`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr) ## dplyr version 1.1.2

mget(ls()) %>% 
  keep(is.data.frame) %>% 
  map(~select(.x, -1)) %>% 
  imap(~mutate(.x, df_no = .y) %>% relocate(df_no)) %>% ## add df name as a column
  list2env(., envir = .GlobalEnv)
  ## use bind_rows instead of list2env if you want a single df with all dataframes
# bind_rows()
```

Comment: that worked perfectly. What about creating a new column with `mutate` to add the df name all along the dataset through all datasets?

Comment: @Bartholomew I added some comments, but if you have further questions, please post a new question and link to this one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `Map` and `Filter`:

```r
Map(\(y) y[-1], Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls())))
```