# How to add custom column to all dataframes in the global environment?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, lapply

This is a follow up question: [How to delete first columns of all dataframes in the global environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76947862/how-to-delete-first-columns-of-all-dataframes-in-the-global-environment)

I have many dataframes (`df1`, `df2`, `df3`, ..., `dfn`)

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3, d=1:3, e=1:3)

df2 <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3, d=1:3, e=1:3)

df3 <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3, d=1:3, e=1:3)

# $df1          #  $df2          #  $df3
# a b d e       #  a b d e       #  a b d e
# 1 1 1 1       #  1 1 1 1       #  1 1 1 1 
# 2 2 2 2       #  2 2 2 2       #  2 2 2 2 
# 3 3 3 3       #  3 3 3 3       #  3 3 3 3 

And so on...
```

I would like to find a way to create a loop or a function that creates a new column `code` to all dataframes in my environment adding the df name column to each df, something that will look like this:

```
$df1                $df2                 $df3
# a b d e code      #  a b d e code      #  a b d e code
# 1 1 1 1  df1      #  1 1 1 1  df2      #  1 1 1 1  df3
# 2 2 2 2  df1      #  2 2 2 2  df2      #  2 2 2 2  df3
# 3 3 3 3  df1      #  3 3 3 3  df2      #  3 3 3 3  df3
```

Any idea?

Comment: Put them all in a list rather than global env

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way -

```
library(dplyr)

ls(pattern = "df\\d+") |>
  mget() |>
  purrr::imap(~.x %>% mutate(code = .y)) |>
  list2env(.GlobalEnv)

df1

#  a b d e code
#1 1 1 1 1  df1
#2 2 2 2 2  df1
#3 3 3 3 3  df1

df2
#  a b d e code
#1 1 1 1 1  df2
#2 2 2 2 2  df2
#3 3 3 3 3  df2

#...
#...
```

By the way, have you considered storing them in a list? It is much easier to manage that.

Comment: And what if I wanted to store everything in a big huge df using rbind?

Comment: In that case you can do `result <- ls(pattern = "df\\d+") |> mget() |> bind_rows(.id = "code")` `result` will have the output of everything combined.

Answer (score 1):

A **base R** approach using `sapply` and `get`

```
sapply(ls(pattern="^df\\d+"), \(x) cbind(get(x), code=x), simplify=F)
$df1
  a b d e code
1 1 1 1 1  df1
2 2 2 2 2  df1
3 3 3 3 3  df1

$df2
  a b d e code
1 1 1 1 1  df2
2 2 2 2 2  df2
3 3 3 3 3  df2

$df3
  a b d e code
1 1 1 1 1  df3
2 2 2 2 2  df3
3 3 3 3 3  df3
```

Answer (score 0):

To show off the list approach (which, despite Ronak and Andre's spectacular answers, is the best approach from a good software engineering practices perspective (i.e. to paraphrase Thomas Lumley, if changing many dataframes in the global environment is the answer, you should usually rethink the question):

```
dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)

purrr::imap(dfs, ~mutate(.x, code = paste0("df", .y)))
```